# How do I create a function that reverses the order of the ... arguments of paste?

Tags: r, arguments

By default,

```
paste('hi', 'there')
[1] "hi there"
```

What if I want a function that does the following?

```
reverse_paste('hi','there')
[1] "there hi "
```

Is there a way to modify the elements of `...` to get the second result?

I am not sure how to handle the `...` arguments in this case, since I want to use the function via `apply` in order to concatenate the elements of data frame made using `expand.grid` (the order of pasting is the opposite of the order of expansion, and both of those orders are important).

Edit: I would like to clarify that I would also like to be able to use the `sep` and `collapse` keyword arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get at the arguments in `...` using `list`. Then you just need to reverse it, add the other arguments, and call `paste`.

```
paste_rev <- function(..., sep=" ", collapse=NULL) {
  arg <- c(rev(list(...)), list(sep=sep, collapse=collapse))
  do.call(paste, arg)
}
paste_rev(c("a1", "a2"), c("b", "c"), sep=".")
## [1] "b.a1" "c.a2"
```

However, if you're using this to `apply` `paste` to a data frame, this won't work as you're not actually using multiple arguments to `paste`, you're instead sending it a vector.

```
out <- expand.grid(a=c("a1", "a2"), b=c("b1", "b2"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
out
##    a  b
## 1 a1 b1
## 2 a2 b1
## 3 a1 b2
## 4 a2 b2
apply(out, 1, paste_rev, collapse=".")
## [1] "a1.b1" "a2.b1" "a1.b2" "a2.b2"
```

Instead, I'd simply reverse the order of the columns before pasting.

```
apply(out[rev(colnames(out))], 1, paste, collapse=".")
## [1] "b1.a1" "b1.a2" "b2.a1" "b2.a2"
```

Or, reverse the elements of each argument individually.

```
paste_rev2 <- function(..., sep=" ", collapse=NULL) {
  arg <- c(lapply(list(...), rev), list(sep=sep, collapse=collapse))
  do.call(paste, arg)
}
apply(out, 1, paste_rev2, collapse=".")
## [1] "b1.a1" "b1.a2" "b2.a1" "b2.a2"
```

For a generic function that could do either, you could add a couple arguments.

```
pasteX <- function(..., sep=" ", collapse=NULL,
                        rev.elements=FALSE, rev.arguments=FALSE) {
  arg <- list(...)
  if(rev.arguments) arg <- rev(arg)
  if(rev.elements) arg <- lapply(arg, rev)
  do.call(paste, c(arg, list(sep=sep, collapse=collapse)))
}
pasteX(c("a", "b"), c(1, 2))
## [1] "a 1" "b 2"
pasteX(c("a", "b"), c(1, 2), rev.elements=TRUE)
## [1] "b 2" "a 1"
pasteX(c("a", "b"), c(1, 2), rev.arguments=TRUE)
## [1] "1 a" "2 b"
pasteX(c("a", "b"), c(1, 2), rev.elements=TRUE, rev.arguments=TRUE)
## [1] "2 b" "1 a"
```